# How to add multiple plugin in same pom.xml file

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I have two project, which run on two different platform Android and Ios. which i am controlling by different suite runner file . when i am trying to run same via Maven , whichever plugin mention last , only that profile run , how can i make working of all.

```
    <plugins>
        <!-- build standalone exe jar -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <skip>false</skip>
                <mainClass>platform.atcios.SuiteRunner</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <skip>false</skip>
                <mainClass>platform.atc.SuiteRunner</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
```

in this , if atc is mention in last , when run for ios , atcios giving build fail error and viceversa.
how to make both work

Answer (score 0):

You need to define different `<executions>` inside the same `<plugin>` tag.

Each `<execution>` may have its own `<configuration>`.